# Движение камеры за персонажем в Canvas

Tags: unity3d

`Canvas'у` установил `Render Mode = Screen Space - Camera` и указал основную камеру, персонаж тоже находится в этом канвасе, так же есть скрипт который по идее должен всегда центрироваться на персонаже, но так как в канвасе указана камера, канвас улетает вместе с персонажем, как с этим бороться ?

И еще нужен ваш совет, я разрабатываю некую аркаду, как лучше ее сделать, с помощью `sprite` или `UI` элементов ?

Делаю через `UI`, но замечаю что удобнее и меньше кода будет, если использую `sprite`, но Canvas позволяет устанавливать якоря и лучше оптимизирует положение элементов. P.S. платформа `Android`.

Comment: Разумеется, ИГРУ лучше делать игровыми объектами (в конкретном примере - sprite), а в канве реализовывать исключительно пользовательский интерфейс.

Comment: Соглашусь с комментатором выше. зачем игровым объектам нужны якоря? Игровые объекты на то и игровые, что привязаны к координатам игрового мира, а не экрана телефона. Размещайте на канвасе любые информативные UI элементы (здоровье, броня, кнопки меню и т.д.), а игровые объекты делайте через Sprite, иначе Вы столкнётесь с огромной кучей проблем.

Answer (score 0):

Может прикрепить камеру к персонажу? Сделать дочерней. Или в скрипте в Update() прописать transform.positiom камеры = character.transform.position